# Org.json Big Decimal support

Tags: java, json, org.json

The *org.json* library doesn’t have `BigDecimal` support. Any idea how and from where I can get the latest library??

I am trying XML to JSON conversion using *org.json* library. But seems like Big Decimal support is not there. Any idea how can I convert the data to instances of type `BigDecimal`?

I tried *20200518* version as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what's wrong without having the xml that you try to parse.
Here is a working example with a dummy xml:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class XMLtoJSON {
      public static String TEST_XML_STRING =
        "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><test>1234123456789.01</test>";
      public static void main(String[] args) {
            JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(TEST_XML_STRING);
            System.out.println("Json parsed from XML: " + xmlJSONObj);
            BigDecimal content = xmlJSONObj.getBigDecimal("test");
            System.out.println("Big decimal value: " + content);
      }
}
```

The output is as expected:

```
Json parsed from XML: {"test":1.23412345678901E12}
Big decimal value: 1234123456789.010009765625
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am converting XML to Json the way you showed. And then converting To String and passing to another application. So in here it sends Exponential value while converting to string. So is there a way that we send original value?

Comment: So, if I understand right you don't want to send the number as '1.23E12' because the next application cannot parse it as a number. In this case, after getting the number as BigDecimal, overwrite the value as plain string: `xmlJSONObj.put("test", content.toPlainString());`

Comment: But there are around 1000 attributes so doing for all will be difficult. Is there any inbuilt feature in the library which will take care of this?

Comment: It's not possible, as far as I know. I'm afraid you have to do it yourself. However, it shouldn't be hard. You get all the 1000 attributes with `xmlJSONObj.keySet()` and you loop through them.